# C# how to detect serial port physical disconnection

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a PC connected to an alarm panel using RS-232 serial port DB-9, the port on the PC side is male, and I'm using a custom cable to connect to the panel(typical 3-wires Rx:pin2,Tx:pin3 and ground:pin5).

I want to detect if the cable is physical disconnected and display a message if that ever happens.

So far I have tried to send a ping signal to the panel every 5 seconds and wait for a response, but the panel appears to not respond to any signal sent from the PC, even though I'm able to receive signals from the panel.

I have also tried to use a fourth wire to check a control pin (CTS:pin8 to be exact) and connect it to any port on the panel that has constant voltage and monitor the `port.CtsHolding` every 5 seconds, but it's always false regardless of the cable condition.

Comment: It sounds like you need to solve the problem of the panel not hearing the PC first.

Comment: As @Jacob Huckins commented, if the alarm panel itself does not have a function to notify connection/disconnection with RTS/CTS or DTR/DSR signal or a function to respond to ping, no matter how the PC or cable is processed, it will be impossible to detect. Please check the specifications of the alarm panel.

Comment: The thing is, there is another port in the panel that allows bidirectional communication and the panel will reply with the same signal that was sent to it. However, using this port will make me lose network functionality, and I can only activate one of the ports at a time. FYI, the port I'm using is labeled printer, while the other port is labeled PC/CRT

Comment: I did notice that when I use the panel with printer port the Tx pin on the PC/CRT port gives a constant -9.91 volt, can this be used with any of the flow control pins? such that -9.91 means connected and 0 is disconnected?

Comment: I think the devil is in the details with this question. The part for me that makes this question hard to answer is that you are asking about communicating with something you have only described as a panel connected with a custom cable, which doesn't give a whole lot to go off. If you are having trouble communicating with the panel that sounds like a technical issue that you should probably solve before trying to detect when it gets unplugged.